# ROWTYPE as input parameter for insert

Tags: oracle

I have procedure which has below parameter rowtype passed from another procedure to this procedure

```
V_mytable_ROW   mytable%ROWTYPE;
```

Earlier the below insert works perfectly for multiple row.

```
insert into mytable values V_mytable_ROW;
```

Since one column to be in sequence I modified the insert as below its works for single input if mutiple row this will not work . I tried with TYPES but i couldn't figure out how to achieve this ... Aany help is appreciated !

```
insert into mytable values (V_mytable_ROW.col_1,
                            V_mytable_ROW.col_2,
                            V_mytable_ROW.col_3,
                            SEQ.NEXTVAL,
                            V_mytable_ROW.col_4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to manipulate the record variable before passing it to the INSERT statement. Something like this:

```
V_mytable_ROW.id := SEQ.NEXTVAL; -- or whatever column name
insert into mytable values V_mytable_ROW;
```